# How do I get Html Source of a Wiktionary page?

Tags: java, mediawiki, wiki, wiktionary

I am struggling withe Wiki Api. How can I simply get a pages html using the API. I know it is possible as I have done it before but I cannot remember how to do it.

Say I want the page source for the page http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bicycle how do I do it. What API do I use. I do not want to look in the Browser?

Comment: In the browser, press `Ctrl`+`U`. If you're not using a browser, what do you use then?

Comment: I would like to use Java. Essnetially there is a URL I can type which will display the page source if typed in a browser. If I create the URL in JAVA it will fetch the page source.

Comment: The URL itself is a query of somesort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Java and [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) you can do this:

```
Document document = Jsoup
        .connect("http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bicycle")
        .get();

Element bodyContent = document.select("div#bodyContent").first();

System.out.println(bodyContent.html());
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the "parse" action of the MediaWiki API assuming you want the HTML:

http://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=bicycle&prop=text&disablepp=1&format=json

If you were looking for the original wikitext you just request a different property:

http://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=bicycle&prop=wikitext&disablepp=1&format=json